# Upload mp4 isnt working

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've trying to do an little script with which i can upload mp4-files to an webserver.
The problem is that it sometimes will upload the files and sometimes it wont.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    Diese Datei hochladen: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" name="uploadfile" />
</form>

<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['uploadfile'] ) ) {
  error_reporting(-1);
  $uploaddir = '/var/www/vhosts/o190.orange.fastwebserver.de/httpdocs/perl/uploads/';
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
  $uploadfile = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $uploadfile);
  print $uploadfile;

  echo '<pre>';
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File sucessfully uploaded.\n";
  } else {
      echo "File couldnt be uploaded!\n";
  }
  print "</pre>";
}
?>
```

I've already changed "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" to 1000M.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Note that html MAX_FILE_SIZE value is in bytes

Comment: @DamienPirsy In the php documentation it says that u can use "M" for Megabyte.

Comment: I mean in the html input